# User Exists on creation, but it actually doesn't in the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having a strange issue with the DB setup for my current application.

As the migrations pass without an issue, however when I try to Seed the DB with some test data it says the data exists and rolls back the transaction.

When I query the DB to check if the record exists it comes back with nil.

At this point I'm lost to where I should be even looking for the culprit.

Any help is appreciated.

**seeds.rb:**

```
User.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', password: 'testing', is_admin: true)
```

**rake db:seed output:**

```
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'john@doe.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

**User.all :**

```
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
=> []
```

Comment: Try `create!`, you will see the error.

Comment: That `SELECT 1 AS one...` suggests that you have a uniqueness validation on the email address and that's probably failing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the user creation is failing because of some validation error i.e., any of the validations on the `User` model are prohibiting the creation of your user record.

What you can do is , update the `seeds.rb` with:

```
User.create!(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', password: 'testing', is_admin: true)
```

**Notice** `create!` instead of `create`.

This way you would know on which validation the user creation failed.

Answer (score 0):

Either use User.create! or code like this

```
user = User.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', password: 'testing', is_admin: true)
```

then run `user.save`